# React Navigation: Scroll to top if tab is the same as active tab

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, tabs, react-navigation

I have a tab-based app. If I'm currently on the first tab, scrolled all the way down, and I click the tab again, I want it to scroll to the top. Is this possible?

I know I should have a scroll view with a reference and then use `this._scrollView.scrollTo(0)`, but how can I detect when the user taps the tabbar and decide whether it is the same tab?

Comment: Is it a react-native or react.js web app?

Comment: what have you tried so far? please add code to your question.

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar is react-native

Comment: @ShahzadMirza tried but no code is actually successful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create your [tab navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html) as follow:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
   // config
},
{
   navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
            // Called when tab is press
        },
    }),
});
```

In order to scroll to top, you can check this solution:

1. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2955#issuecomment-343422076
2. https://snack.expo.io/HJp9mEQkG

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated.

Comment: @AnBisw not for now. In the future maybe yes but for now it not deprecated, and you always can use hooks.

Answer (score 16):

For who is looking for a solution for react native, if you are using react navigation, you need to import ScrollView, FlatList or SectionList from react-navigation instead of react-native.

eg.

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-navigation';
```

You can find the details on the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/scrollables/

**UPDATE**

If you are using react navigation v5

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

function CustomComponent() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(ref);

  return <FlatList ref={ref} {/* settings */} />;
}
```

docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top

Answer (score 9):

> React Navigation 5.x

The simplest solution they have provided is, just pass the ref of your scrollable component to their `useScrollToTop` hook.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Albums() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(ref);

  return <ScrollView ref={ref}>{/* content */}</ScrollView>;
}
```

[Snack.expo.io Example](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=useScrollToTop%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.4.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.7.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.4.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.3.7%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E3.10.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E0.7.3%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.4.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.14.0&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fuse-scroll-to-top.js)

[Documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top/)

Answer (score 5):

For react navigation 5, simply use the `useScrollToTop` hook from `@react-navigation/native`. Their documentation outlines how to use it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-scroll-to-top.

From their docs:

Functional Components

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { useScrollToTop } from '@react-navigation/native';

function Albums() {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(ref);

  return <ScrollView ref={ref}>{/* content */}</ScrollView>;
}
```

Class Components

```
class Albums extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ScrollView ref={this.props.scrollRef}>{/* content */}</ScrollView>;
  }
}

// Wrap and export
export default function(props) {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  useScrollToTop(ref);

  return <Albums {...props} scrollRef={ref} />;
}
```

Sidenote: You can use this on any component that scrolls and has access to the `navigation` prop. As in, you could have multiple scrollable components under a given screen (if you were using something like `react-native-tab-view`) and this would work fine for both of them, individually.

Answer (score 1):

**tabBarOnPress** in **navigationOptions**. Callback to handle tap events; the argument is an object containing:

the `previousScene`: { route, index }: the scene which we are leaving.
the `scene`: { route, index } that was tapped.
the `jumpToIndex` method that can perform the navigation for you.

so in your case just use scene object to check which tab is pressed.

check more on [react navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-navigator.html).